# Regular language as finite union of periodic sets

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-sets

Is it true that every regular language can be expressed as a finite union of periodic sets?  In other words, if $L$ is regular, then do there exist finite sets $A_1,\dots,A_n,B_1,\dots,B_n$ such that

$$L = A_1 \cdot B_1^* \cup \cdots \cup A_n \cdot B_n^*.$$

I know this is true for regular languages over a unary alphabet, but I'm not sure about general alphabets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every language of this form can be represented as a regular expression without nested Kleene star. That is, its [star height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_height) is $1$. The [star height hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_height_problem) is strict, and in particular, it is known that the language $(a^*b^*c)^*$ cannot be represented in that form. An example over a binary alphabet would be $(aa(ab)^*bb(ab)^*)^*$.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @YuvalFilmus is perfectly fine, and points you to the import notion of *star height*. But let me add a little bit more. We will show that languages of your form give a proper subset of the languages of star height one. But first, some musings what might come close to your form.

**General Regular Languages**

First, probably the closest form to yours for regular $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$, accepted by a complete deterministic automaton $A = (\Sigma, Q, \delta, q_0, F)$.
For $q \in Q$ and $E \subseteq Q$, write $L_{q, E}(A)$ for the language
accepted by $(\Sigma, Q, \delta, q, E)$, i.e., changing the start state to $q$
and the set of final states to $E$.
Then, we can write
$$ 
 L = \bigcup_{ q \in F } L_{q_0, q}(A) L_{q, \{q\}}(A)^*
$$
This result seems to be folklore and follows easily. A more refined variant of this decomposition appears in the book *Automata, Languages and Machines, Volume A* by S. Eilenberg, under the name *iterated up-decomposition*.

**Commutative and Bounded Regular Languages**

Others forms, more close to yours, and being proper generalizations of the unary language case you mentioned, could be given for the bounded and commutative regular languages. A language is *commutative*, if it is closed under permutation of letters. For example, $\{ab,ba\}$ is commutative, whereas $\{ab\}$ is not. A language $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is *bounded*, if $L \subseteq w_1^* \cdots w_n^*$
for words $w_i \in \Sigma^*$. In what follows, let us denote by $\diamond$ the [shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffle_algebra) of two languages, and, for $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$, by $L^{\diamond,*} = \bigcup_{n \ge 0} \underbrace{L \diamond \ldots \diamond L}_{\mbox{$n$ times}}$ the *iterated shuffle*. Also, by $\operatorname{perm} : 2^{\Sigma^*} \to 2^{\Sigma*}$ denote the *permutational closure*, or *commutative closure*, i.e. adding all words that are permutations.
For example, $\operatorname{perm}(\{ab\}) = \{ab,ba\}$.

Note that $L \subseteq w^*$ is regular iff  $L = w^n(w^p)^*$ for some $n, p \ge 0$. This is implied by noting that $\{ n : w^n \in L \}$ is ultimately periodic (it could be viewed as a regular unary language).

By a result of [Ginsburg/Spanier](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-05/S0002-9939-1966-0201310-3/) we have

> A language $L \subseteq w_1^* \cdots w_r^*$ is regular iff it is a finite union of languages of the form $L_1 \cdots L_r$, where each $L_i \subseteq w_i^*$ is regular.

Also, if $\Sigma = \{a_1, \ldots, a_k\}$ and $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is commutative and regular, it is [possible](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00482) to show that
$$
 L = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \operatorname{perm}(u_i) \diamond \operatorname{perm}(N_i)^{\diamond,*}
$$
for finite sets $N_i \subseteq a_1^* \cup \ldots \cup a_k^*$ with $|N_i \cap a_j^*| \le 1$.

Also, as stated [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-030-21363-3_13) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.04042), a regular language $L$ over $\Sigma = \{a_1, \ldots, a_k\}$ is commutative iff
$$
 L = \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{i,1} \diamond \ldots \diamond U_{i,k}
$$
for unary regular languages $U_{i,j} \subseteq a_j^*$
with $i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ and $j \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$.

All these results are closely related. Note that for unary languages, they all reduce to the form you have stated.

**A Necessary Condition for Languages of your Form**

The condition I will state involves topology and infinite words. It yields, for example, that $b^*a$ and $(b^*a)^*$ could not be written in your form. The latter has star height two, note that star height could be characterized by *cycle rank*, see [Eggan's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_height#Eggan%27s_theorem).
However, I do want to give a self-contained, and different, argument here, not based on star height. Let $\Sigma^{\omega}$ be the set of infinite words over $\Sigma$. Define an operator $W : 2^{\Sigma^*} \to 2^{\Sigma^{\omega}}$ by, for $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$,
$$
 W(L) = \{ \xi \in \Sigma^{\omega} \mid \mbox{ $\xi$ has infinitely many prefixes in $L$ } \}.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
 W(b^*a) & = \emptyset \\ 
 W((b^*a)^*) & = \{ \xi \in \Sigma^{\omega} \mid \mbox{$\xi$ has infinitely many $a$'s. } \}.
\end{align*}
Observe that
$$
 W(U \cup V) = W(U) \cup V(V),
$$
as, if $\xi \in W(U\cup V)$, then, by the pigenhole principle, at least one of $U$ or $V$, or both, must contain infinitely many prefixes of $\xi$. Also, in your form we could assume all the sets $A_i$ are singletons, as concatenation distributes over union.

Let us inspect languages of the form $L = u(u_1 + \ldots + u_n)^*$, which are the parts of your form.
Set $\Gamma = \{ b_1, \ldots, b_n \}$, an auxiliary alphabet, and consider the homomorphism $h : \Gamma \to \Sigma^*$ given by $h(b_i) = u_i$, i.e., substituting each letter by the corresponding word. This homomorphism could also be applied to infinite words in $\Gamma^{\omega}$. We have
$$
 W(u(u_1 + \ldots + u_n)^*) = \{ uh(\xi) \mid \xi \in \Gamma^{\omega} \}. 
$$
In particular, if all the set $B_i$ are singletons, $W(L)$ is finite, and $W(L) \ne \emptyset$ for every infinite language of your form.

By the last observation, $b^*a$ could not be written in your form. So, this is a very simple example, even of star height one.
But let us show that $L = (b^*a)^*$ could also not be written that way. Assume it could be, then the set of infinite words, which all have an infinite number of $a$'s in it, could be written in terms of a homomorphism
$h : \Gamma^* \to \Sigma^*$ as outlined above, i.e.,
$$
 \{ \xi \in \Sigma^{\omega} \mid \mbox{$\xi$ has infinitely many $a$'s. } \} = u h(\Gamma^{\omega})
$$
for some $u \in \Sigma^*$.
Let $m = \{ |h(x)| : x \in \Gamma \} + |u|$.
Then $ub^maaaaa\cdots$ is in this language,
and this implies $h(x) \in b^+$ for some $x \in \Gamma$.
But then $ubbbbbbb\cdots \in uh(\Gamma^{\omega})$, which is a contradiction, as it only contains a finite number of $a$'s. Hence, $(b^*a)^*$ could not be written that way. $\square$